# Styling issues with Chartist + VueJs + Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js, vuetify.js, chartist.js

I am following the documentation provided [here](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html) for a simple line chart. All the dependent packages were added using `yarn` and could it be possible that the attached css/scss isnt bootstrapped correctly?

**Issue**

The rendered chart is all black and ugly as seen in the screenshot possibly because of missing css, not sure.

**packages used**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "chartist": "^0.11.0",
     "vue": "2.5.0",
    "vue-typed": "git+https://github.com/icfr/vue-typed.git#update_vue",
    "vuetify": "^0.17.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.38"
}
```

**Vue Js template - linechart.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-content>
     <v-container grid-list-xl>
            <h2>Line chart using chartist.js</h2>
            <div class ="ct-chart"></div>
     </v-container>
   </v-content>
</template>
```

**TS code**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { Component, Prop } from "vue-typed";
import * as Chartist from "chartist";
const template = require("./linechart.vue");

export default class ChartistLineChart extends Vue {
mounted() {
    let chart = this.$el.getElementsByClassName("ct-chart")[0];
    let data: Chartist.IChartistData = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        series: [[740, 790, 720, 900, 890, 880, 840],
                 [140, 390, 100, 900, 190, 180, 400]
                ]
    };
    let options: Chartist.ILineChartOptions = {
        fullWidth: true,
        chartPadding: {
            right: 40
          }
    };
    let lineChart = new Chartist.Line(chart, data, options);
}
```

What am i possibly missing? thanks!

[image: Line chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing to include styles for Chartist.

https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/getting-started.html#one-two-three-css

Add it in your `<meta>` tag:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/chartist/dist/chartist.min.css">`

or import using webpack loader (if you have it configured) as any file in JS:

`import 'bower_components/chartist/dist/chartist.min.css'`

Comment: Why would i hard code such a reference? it beats the purpose of compiling and building . I am pulling in the necessary packages and packing it using webpack - the "packaged/compiled" version must contain the refrence and one shouldnt reference any hard coded path

Comment: @Jaya That's why I wrote about webpack way as well. Importing from node_modules in a common practice. Read the docs of your lib.

Comment: How to do it in a NPM way? Why the fck didn't they include this step in the documentation at https://github.com/Yopadd/vue-chartist??

Answer (score 0):

You can import the Chartist scss directly into your Vue component.

```
npm install chartist --save
```

Then the following code snippet will get you up and running with Chartist:

```
<template>

   <div class="my-chart ct-chart"></div>

</template>

<script>

   import Chartist from 'chartist';
   ...

</script>

<style lang="scss">

    @import "~chartist/dist/scss/chartist";
    ...

</style>
```

That will make the `ct-chart` class available while still using all the Vue build niceties.